# No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined expected single bean but found 0

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

keep getting this error building a spring data jpa application..

here are my files:

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

        <jpa:repositories base-package="at.ticketbox.repositories" />

<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
 For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->
<context:component-scan base-package="at.ticketbox" />

 <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 

<!-- Load Hibernate related configuration -->
<import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />
```

**hibernate-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        ">

<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />


<!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->
<!-- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html -->                           
<!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html -->
<!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Session.html -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
             p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
             p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
             p:packagesToScan="at.ticketbox"/>

<!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
            p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driver}"
            p:url="${jdbc.url}"
            p:username="${jdbc.username}"
            p:password="${jdbc.password}"
            />

<bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

<!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
<tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

**spring.properties**

```
# database properties
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ticketbox
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect 
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=

#hibernate properties
hibernate.config=/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml
```

**and the hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<!-- We're using MySQL database so the dialect needs to MySQL as well-->
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect </property>
<!-- Enable this to see the SQL statements in the logs-->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<!-- This will drop our existing database and re-create a new one.
        Existing data will be deleted! -->
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
<property name="lazy">false</property>
```

I still keep getting the "[ No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined]" expected single bean but found 0

but isn´t the EntityManagerFactory already defined in the hibernate-context.xml???
thx for your help

as wished, the stacktrace:

```
28.02.2012 11:2

7:13 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\programme\product\11.1.0\client_1;C:\Program Files\Xuggle\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\
28.02.2012 11:27:13 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:ticketbox' did not find a matching property.
28.02.2012 11:27:13 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
28.02.2012 11:27:13 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 779 ms
28.02.2012 11:27:13 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
28.02.2012 11:27:13 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
28.02.2012 11:27:14 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Feb 28 11:27:14 CET 2012]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring.properties]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'dataSource' of type [class org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'entityManagerFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@102b2b6: defining beans [statusRepository,hardwareRepository,contactRepository,userRepository,softwareRepository,hardwareModelRepository,hardwareTypeRepository,accountRepository,org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,accountController,contactController,hardwareController,hardwareModelController,softwareController,statusController,userController,accountDAO,contactDAO,hardwareDAO,softwareDAO,statusDAO,userDAO,homeController,accountService,contactService,hardwareModelService,hardwareService,hardwareTypeService,softwareService,statusService,userService,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,entityManagerFactory,dataSource,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@102b2b6: defining beans [statusRepository,hardwareRepository,contactRepository,userRepository,softwareRepository,hardwareModelRepository,hardwareTypeRepository,accountRepository,org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,accountController,contactController,hardwareController,hardwareModelController,softwareController,statusController,userController,accountDAO,contactDAO,hardwareDAO,softwareDAO,statusDAO,userDAO,homeController,accountService,contactService,hardwareModelService,hardwareService,hardwareTypeService,softwareService,statusService,userService,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,entityManagerFactory,dataSource,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'statusRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:537)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:339)
    ... 28 more
28.02.2012 11:27:17 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'statusRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:537)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:339)
    ... 28 more
28.02.2012 11:27:17 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error listenerStart
28.02.2012 11:27:17 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SCHWERWIEGEND: Context [/ticketbox] startup failed due to previous errors
28.02.2012 11:27:17 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
28.02.2012 11:27:17 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/ticketbox] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
28.02.2012 11:27:18 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
28.02.2012 11:27:18 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
28.02.2012 11:27:18 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/26  config=null
28.02.2012 11:27:18 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5030 ms
```

Thx again for your help

Answer (score 4):

The bean with id `entityManagerFactory` should implement the interface: `javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory`

But your `entityManagerFactory` is of type `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` and that does not implement the `EntityManagerFactory`.

*BTW I have the feeling that you mixed JPA and pure Hibernate (not the JPA part of Hibernate). That will not work. I would recomend to use JPA and Hibernate as JPA Provider*

Comment: Could you give me some examples or maybe tutorial how to use Hibernate as JPA Provider? I have also mixed unfortunately JPA and pure Hibernate.

Comment: @woyaru: sorry I dont have a tutorial. But to see JPA/Hibernate in action you could create a Spring Roo project, it shows very well how JPA/Hibernate work.